# What exactly is a basis of neighborhoods?

Tags: general-topology

What exactly is a basis of neighborhoods and is it the same as a neighborhood basis?

Comment: change the tag, should be general topology instead of algebraic topology

Comment: base rather than basis (basis  is used in (linear) algebra, base in topology)

Comment: "Basis" was used in the context in which I read it which was a cohomology paper.

Comment: I'd guess that including where you encountered this (with reference, perhaps link) would improve the question. (I suppose that [missing context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) is the reason why this post [got a few close votes](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1059655).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are the same: Let $X$ be a space and $x \in X$.  A set $\mathcal{N}$ of neighbourhoods of $x$ (so $x \in \operatorname{int}(N)$ for all $N \in \mathcal{N}$) is a neighbourhood base at $x$ iff for any neighbourhood $O$ of $x$ there is some $N \in \mathcal{N}$ such that $N \subseteq O$.

Also see the first section of [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_system)

Comment: Why we wouldn't just say that a neighbourhood base is a collection of any neighbourhoods of "x"? It satisfies the criteriea: "For any neighbourhood O of "x" there's some N in neighborhood base such that N belongs or equals to O.